# Best way to persist an array of images?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a way to persist images to an array (or similar) that can be accessed after the app has closed an relaunched -- sorting the images by date is also required. I'm currently able to store the the images to the app's NSDocumentDirectory with the following code:

```
-(NSString *)currentDateandTime
{
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy_HHmmss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    return dateString;
}

-(void)saveImageToDocuments
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *date = [self currentDateandTime];

    NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_image.png",date]];
}
```

This means I've got images where the date/time is in the filenames of the image. What is the best way to go about storing these images in an array or dictionary AND sorting them by date/time. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would save the file names and dates in a plist file which is an array of dictionaries of format: `@{ @"filename" : imageFileName, @"date": imageDate }`.

When you load that plist into an `NSArray`, you can easily sort it by date by specifying your own comparison method. e.g:

```
NSArray *filenames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSArray *sortedFilenames = [filenames sortedArrayUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *dict1, NSDictionary *dict2) 
{
    NSDate *date1 = dict1[@"date"];
    NSDate *date2 = dict2[@"date"];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the image data and the dates in some dictionaries, then store those dictionaries in an array, then use NSKeyedArchiver to archive the array.

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:imageDictionary toFile:@"imagesArray"];
```

Then when you want to retrieve it:

```
 NSArray * retrievedImages = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"imagesArray"];
```

Then just compare the dates in the various dictionaries in the retrieved array.